# Google Forms: Disable the "back" option on a multi-section quiz?

Tags: google-forms

I would like to create a quiz whereby respondents watch video and answer questions about it. It is important that the respondents only watch the video once.

In order to do this, I have split the form into two sections. The first section containing the video (uploaded from YouTube), and the second section containing the questions. However, I noticed that it is possible to go back to the first section after moving on to the second.

Can anyone advise on how I can ensure that the respondents are unable to rewatch the video after seeing the questions?

Many thanks!

[image: Section 1 & 2]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Does the respondents are any user on the web having the form view link or only users from the same organization? Are you looking for a build-in function? Are you or your organization able to manage the respondents computer or to ask them to install a web browser extension?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can prevent the user from using the `Back` button in Google Forms. Besides, a knowledgeable user can open the video directly in YouTube in another tab and view it as many times they like.

Perhaps it would be easiest to very politely explain to the users that they should only watch the video once, and then test how well they remember it in the next page — "Please watch the video once only. We are not testing *you*, but testing how well the *video* conveys its message."